# What does "taking a $6.5 billion charge" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean **taking a $6.5 billion FINE**?

Boeing posted a record annual loss of nearly $12 billion, taking a $6.5 billion charge in the fourth quarter on its newest airplane which it now doesn’t expect to debut until 2023, more than two years behind schedule.

Source:https://www.cnbc.com/2021/01/27/boeing-ba-q4-2020-earnings.html

Comment: It means that Boeing is writing down (deducting) $6.5 billion from its balance sheet (as a result of losses accrued from the Boeing 737 Max debacle,) causing it to plunge deep into the red.

Answer (score 0):

It does not mean fine, because there was no state or national government *fining* Boeing. Instead, it means *debit* (or *loss*).

> b: a debit to an account
>
> The purchase was a charge.

From here:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge